# Confusion with passing character pointer array by reference

Tags: c, pointers, local-variables

How can I pass an array of character pointers by reference? I tried passing with `&tokens` and de-referencing in `func()` but it still won't work.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char* tokens[10])
{
    char word[10] = "Hello\0";
    tokens[0] = word;
}

int main()
{
    char* tokens[10];

    func(tokens);
    printf("%s", tokens[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
He����
```

Comment: why on Earth are you adding a `\0` at the end of the string? The `\0` is added implicitly. Your string will be terminated by _two_ `\0`s.

Comment: @WalterTross I did not know this was the case

Comment: What do you mean? C does not support references. You can pas a pointer though, but being a 3-star programmer is a clear indicator of bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically allocate the memory using [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) to return and later de-allocate it using [`free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free). Returning a local variable from a function wouldn't be right because that memory is on stack and won't be available when the function completes its execution.

Here's your working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(char* tokens[10])
{
    char* word = malloc( 10 );
    strcpy( word, "Hello!" );
    tokens[0] = word;
}

int main() 
{
    char* tokens[10];

    func(tokens);
    printf("%s", tokens[0]);

    free( tokens[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello!
```

Here's the live example: https://ideone.com/LbN2NX

Comment: That's a side-problem, but not what OP asks about. OPs code contains more problems which are explained in every C textbook. Re your code: don't cast `void *` to pointers. There is no need and every unnecessary cast is one more place the compiler can't warn you about a problem. (oh, and there is no need to dynamically allocate the array at all).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite : Thanks for pointing out. I'll update my answer. What do you mean by there's no need to dynamically allocate the array?

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote. What is unclear about this sentence?